# Is it possible to organize pub keys in groups using GnuPG?

Tags: gpg, macos

I would like to separate imported pub keys (`gpg --import`) in groups to organize them.

For example, I have a bunch of pub keys I would like to keep for a long time vs others that I need to use once or twice and eventually delete them (without groups, I have to manually inspect all keys).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out using `--keyring` and `--no-default-keyring`.

Added a few functions to `.zshrc` to make things more efficient (on macOS, default keyring is called `pubring.gpg`).

```bsh
# Search keys.openpgp.org
function search-keys() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Usage: search-keys [keyring] id"
    return 1
  fi
  if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    2=$1
    1=pubring.gpg
  fi
  if [ $1 != "pubring.gpg" ] && [ $1 != "tmp.gpg" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Invalid keyring $1"
    return 1
  fi
  gpg --keyring $1 --no-default-keyring --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --search-keys $2
}

# Import public key
function import() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Usage: import [keyring] /path/to/pubkey.asc"
    return 1
  fi
  if [ -z "$2" ]; then
    2=$1
    1=pubring.gpg
  fi
  if [ $1 != "pubring.gpg" ] && [ $1 != "tmp.gpg" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Invalid keyring $1"
    return 1
  fi
  gpg --keyring $1 --no-default-keyring --import $2
}

# List public keys
function list-keys() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    1=pubring.gpg
  fi
  if [ $1 != "pubring.gpg" ] && [ $1 != "tmp.gpg" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Invalid keyring $1"
    return 1
  fi
  gpg --keyring $1 --no-default-keyring --list-keys $2
}

# Encrypt message for id
function encrypt() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Usage: encrypt id"
    return 1
  fi
  gpg --keyring "tmp.gpg" --encrypt --sign --armor -r 0xC1323A377DE14C8B -r $1
}

# Decrypt and decode encrypted file
function decrypt() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    printf "%s\n" "Usage: decrypt /path/to/encrypted.asc"
    return 1
  fi
  gpg --decrypt $1 | perl -MMIME::QuotedPrint -0777 -nle 'print decode_qp($_)'
}
```

Replace `0xC1323A377DE14C8B` with your public key.